# Can I use the same IPsec tunnel for two VRF?

Tags: ipsec, vrf

I have two routers linked by two logical links in two different VRF. I should move one router to another site and use Internet to keep the same connectivity. Since I use private IP addresses in my VRF, I thought about creating an IPsec tunnel over Internet with a new interface with public IP and then use that tunnel with my VRF. However, it is not clear if I need a tunnel per VRF or only one for both. Thank in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cisco routers have a feature called VRF aware IPSec. It is available in version 12.2(33) and later. 
Here’s a brief [introduction](https://community.cisco.com/t5/security-documents/vrf-aware-ipsec-cheat-sheet/ta-p/3109449).

Other companies may have similar features.